# What's the correct way to get an Image in to a Byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to make use of an image pasted from the clipboard, like a screenshot.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
public void PasteImage(Image pasteImage)
{
    MemoryStream image = new MemoryStream();
    pasteImage.Save(image, pasteImage.RawFormat);
    image.Position=0;
    byte[] byteImage = image.ToArray();
```

On the line:

```
pasteImage.Save(image, pasteImage.RawFormat);
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred
>   in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

I'm following previous stackoverflow posts I've found on this topic, such as [How to compare two images using byte arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764280/c-sharp-image-to-byte-and-byte-to-image), and [How to convert image in byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-in-byte-array), and just can't get it to work.

I'm wondering if there is something specific about images retrieved from the clipboard. I'm using this code to fetch the image:

```
    if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
    {
        Image pasteImage = GetClipboardImage();
        PasteImage(pasteImage);
    }
```

**EDIT**

This is the code behind GetClipboardImage():

```
public Image GetClipboardImage()
        {
            System.Drawing.Image returnImage = null;
            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
                returnImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
            }
            return returnImage;
        }
```

If I put a breakpoint on the line that errors I can see that both pasteImage and pastImage.RawFormat are not null:

[image]

[image]

This looks relevant as an example Ill have a crack at that and report back: [How can I get an image out of the clipboard without losing the alpha channel in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998655/how-can-i-get-an-image-out-of-the-clipboard-without-losing-the-alpha-channel-in)

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on that line.. is `pasteImage` or `RawFormat` `null`?

Comment: It has to be the calling code, I would guess that pasteImage is null.  The only difference in the PasteImage snippet that I do is without the image.Position and I use GetBuffer() instead of ToArray()

Comment: I don't think images or files for that matter are directly copied to the clipboard. A reference to the original file location is copied and once you paste it does the copying. Copy an image to the clipboard then delete the image then try to paste. So in other words as far as I understand, you cannot get the bytes of an image from the clipboard because technically the clipboard doesn't contain an image.

Comment: since you are getting a NullReferenceException then probably the pastImage parameter is null, you can check it like this just to make sure: if (pasteImage == null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("pastImage is null"); then run the application in debug mode and check if you can see the "pastImage is null" message in the output window, if yes then i am correct.

Comment: What is the code behind GetClipboardImage();
Seems to me that this should be Clipboard.GetImage();

Comment: Also see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getimage(v=vs.100).aspx and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998655/how-can-i-get-an-image-out-of-the-clipboard-without-losing-the-alpha-channel-in

Comment: I've updated my question in response to the above comments, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [MSDN article for Save Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx), you might want to try:

Instead of

```
pasteImage.Save(image, pasteImage.RawFormat);
```

try

```
pasteImage.Save(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.RawFormat)
```